# Python's datatable f-expression fails

Tags: python, py-datatable

My most simple attempt to perform the [**Perform Groupby Calculations**](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/start/using-datatable.html#perform-groupby-calculations) in its [documentation](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/start/using-datatable.html#using-datatable) fails:

```
import datatable
import numpy

rahmen = datatable.Frame({
    'x': (numpy.arange(10) / 2.).astype(int)
    , 'y': numpy.random.uniform(size=10)
})

print(rahmen)
rahmen[:, sum(f.y), by("x")]
```

```
   |     x         y
   | int64   float64
-- + -----  --------
 0 |     0  0.250715
 1 |     0  0.287247
 2 |     1  0.588283
 3 |     1  0.68047 
 4 |     2  0.172261
 5 |     2  0.131789
 6 |     3  0.985102
 7 |     3  0.33328 
 8 |     4  0.673836
 9 |     4  0.217263
[10 rows x 2 columns]
```

---

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-b77d3dcfc678> in <module>
      8 
      9 print(rahmen)
---> 10 rahmen[:, sum(f.y), by("x")]

NameError: name 'f' is not defined
```

Do I need to do something specific to make f-expressions work?

UPDATE: So *this* works:

```
rahmen[:, datatable.sum(datatable.f.y), datatable.by("x")]
```

but it's obviously clumsy, and even if I give up on using dt for datetimes elsewhere and everywhere and use it as datatable alias instead (or any other short alias), it defeats the point of the module using f-expressions, and is inconsistent with the documentation. A `from datatable import *` (or more restrictive)
could perhaps work instead, but there are some fairly obvious reasons to want to avoid that.

Comment: Where the code says `rahmen[:, sum(f.y), by("x")]`, what do you expect the `f` to mean? Why? "Do I need to do something specific to make f-expressions work?" What do you mean by "f-expression"? If you got this term from the documentation, did you try reading that documentation more carefully in order to understand what is missing? Did you try to find an example in the documentation and make sure you can get it working?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, I expect f-expression to mean what it means in the documentation that I did, indeed read, and carefully. Hence my use of the term. And using the example in the documentation was not possible as the data file they used was not provided. So I created a MWE, as per usual practice. Apologies I did not fully qualify everything in my question.

Comment: @python_user, I had tried that for what it was worth, even though it doesn't make sense to me because the examples don't use dt.f or dt.by (where they `import datatable as dt` in place of my import). In any event, it gives `TypeError: 'datatable.FExpr' object is not iterable`

Comment: Try `print(f'{rahmen}')`.

Comment: "@KarlKnechtel, I expect f-expression to mean what it means in the documentation that I did, indeed read, and carefully. Hence my use of the term." I don't see `f-expression` used as a term on that page (and I checked with my browser's in-page search). I do see code that uses something called `f`. Keep in mind that none of this is *magical*; `import`ing a module can't change the syntax of the language. Here, `f` is just another variable name, which is supposed to get defined when you import it *from* the module.

Comment: In other words, it works as described in the previous section: "Filter rows via an expression using the following. *In this example, mean, sd, f are all symbols imported from datatable*:" When using third-party libraries, it is expected that you understand the fundamentals of the language. In this case, the missing piece is the idea of importing *from* a module (rather than just importing the module), like `from <module_name> import <whatever>`.

Comment: @martineau that's an f-*string*; as far as I can tell, the terminology "f-expression" doesn't refer to anything. The reported error is a `NameError` that comes from either a simple typo/oversight, or a failure to understand Python's import system properly.

Comment: "f-expression" per se  is in other areas of the documentation: https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual/f-expressions.html. It seems to be a hard-coded alias to the frame being subscripted, akin to "AS f" in sql. And "g" is possible as well, apparently, for things like joins (e.g. output [18] at https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual/comparison_with_rdatatable.html). I had also tried explicitly `from datatable import f`, with still no joy

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: FWIW, it does refer to something within the context of an `f-string` in Python, which has something called an `f_expression` which is surrounded by `{` and `}` brackets — see [Formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals). That is what I thought the OP was referring to.

Comment: That makes sense, but the name is really only used for the sake of showing off the grammar of the Python language. It's not terminology you'd expect to see in ordinary tutorials.

Comment: thanks for the observation @GoneAsync. It should have been added at the top during the import; if you do not mind, could you raise an issue on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/h2oai/datatable/issues), so the docs can be improved? thanks

Answer (score 1):

add below line at top of your file

```
from datatable import f, sum
```

Comment: then f and sum become protected everywhere. These are too common, and carry too much potential to introduce conflict

Comment: in that case, you can just `dt.f` or `dt.sum` instead. `dt.sum` also has a method option(`f.y.sum()`) that you could use. Please feel free to contribute to the library via Github with suggestions on improvements to the docs.